# Unable to store data using system stream in c# windows store app

Tags: c#, windows, windows-store-apps

I am trying to store data of my program in an xml file using xmlSerializer but it is not letting me to create Stream file.

```
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<transaction>))  
using (StreamWriter wr = new StreamWriter("data.xml"))
    {
       xs.Serialize(wr, this.records);
    }
```

Error: Argument 1 cannot convert into Stream.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error, it seems that ObserverableCollection cannot be serialized.

Howerver I doubt it.

But you need to keep in mind that you're not able to write to the disk in such an easy way when you're creating a Windows Store application.

Windows Store have a limited area where they can save files on the disk, and they're accessed through a section called 'StorageFolder'.

I suggest you take a look at this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh758325.aspx).

Maybe you need to think about your design since you're not able what you want to do, unless storing it in another folder.